# How to minify the cached twig templates HTML and inline CSS, JS code in symfony2?

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm using symfony 2.3 and I want to serve a minified HTML and the inline CSS and JS.

I know that there are some bundles that do that but it minifying every thing on the fly using the onKernelResponse event listener, I tried "MatTheCat/HtmlCompressorBundle" but after checking the server response time, request total time and memory usage after using it I found that these performance measures became worst.

I think the best way to accomplish this task is to do the minify operation while compiling the twig files so it will be minified in production environment only.

I already use the assetic bundle to minify the js and css files.

How can I accomplish this task?

Answer (score 0):

This may be late, but you can do your own bundle. I write my own bundle to include css/js, handle duplicated includes, and then have a command to minify them and store in web folder to serve.